# Can't alter $lostpassword_url

Tags: password

I need to change the href of "retrieve password" but I can't seem to change the `$lostpassword_url` in `wp_lostpassword_url();`

I have this filter, which apparently gets called in `wp-login.php`:

```
function wp_lostpassword_url( $redirect = '' ) {
    $args = array( 'action' => 'lostpassword' );
    if ( !empty($redirect) ) {
        $args['redirect_to'] = $redirect;
    }

    $lostpassword_url = add_query_arg( $args, network_site_url('wp-login.php', 'login') );


    /**
     * Filters the Lost Password URL.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     *
     * @param string $lostpassword_url The lost password page URL.
     * @param string $redirect         The path to redirect to on login.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'lostpassword_url', $lostpassword_url, $redirect );
}
```

and when I change it to:

```
$lostpassword_url =  'new_page';
```

nothing changes, so im probably changing something in the wrong place.

Question is then, how do i change this href?

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the url of the "Lost your password?"-link on the logging screen, right?

[image: Wordpress logging screen]

So to change the url you can use the "lostpassword_url" filter.

```
function change_url ( $url ) {  $url = 'www.google.de'; return $url; }


function change_something() 
{ 
    add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'change_url' );     
}

add_action ( 'login_head', 'change_something' );
```